# How to transfer the various data types from C++ to python?

Tags: python, c++

I have some code in C++ which is modifying the values stored in three arrays (x, y and r) at every time step. The number of data points in each of the arrays x, y and r at every time step is around 90 lakhs.

What I want is, at every time step, after the values in the arrays x, y and r have been updated through the code written in C++, all the three array values must be transferred by some means to the python so that I can make a pictorial representation of some kind.

I couldn't find out how to write the code in C++ to do the pictorial representation, that's why  I need to transfer the array values at every time step from C++ to python.

Is there any way to do this ? Please suggest a method

Comment: Define pictorial representation?

Comment: Please follow the [tour] and read [ask]. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, and is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation. The official documentation for Python has an entire section on how to interface with C or C++ code.

Comment: try to plot those circles using c++ itself : [circle drawing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/draw-circle-c-graphics/)

Comment: Did you read *all* the documentation of [Python](http://python.org/)? It is written in English. Regarding C++, read [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) and the documentation of your C++ compiler, perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). If your OS is Linux, read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), and study [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Please provide some [mre] in your next questions

Comment: If you want some graphical display, consider using [FLTK](http://fltk.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/) if that is allowed to you. Both have been interfaced to Python

Comment: Read also https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html ; when I said "read *all* the documentation of Python" I really meant it. Budget a week of work to read documentation. And study the *source code* of Python (or of FLTK or of Qt) they all are *open source software*

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11), a sample program [snippet](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/cast/stl.html):

Then you can seamlessly call c++ code from python.

```cpp
/* ... definition ... */

class MyClass {
    std::vector<int> contents;
};

/* ... binding code ... */

py::class_<MyClass>(m, "MyClass")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def_readwrite("contents", &MyClass::contents);
```

> pybind11 is a lightweight header-only library that exposes C++ types
> in Python and vice versa, mainly to create Python bindings of existing
> C++ code. Its goals and syntax are similar to the excellent
> Boost.Python library by David Abrahams: to minimize boilerplate code
> in traditional extension modules by inferring type information using
> compile-time introspection.

If you are using separated programs, we may choose some IPC  mechanisms

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipes to transfer data between processes. In linux you can put your data to the standard out and pipe it into your python with '|'. You can also create named pipes to achieve this with 'mkfifo'. I am pretty sure you can probably do something like this in Windows as well, but I don't know how.

Edit: Look up pipes in Windows [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipes)